# Code completion stop working when starting angular server on Intellij Idea 2020.1

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, intellij-idea

This is fresh ionic/angular project, no actual code more than the boiler plate by ionic blank template.

Code completion works perfectly before starting the angular server but as soon as it start, code completion/suggestions stop working.

I have tried the following:

A) invalidate cache/restart

B)

1. disable the angular and angularjs plugin
2. restart IDE

C)

1. Delete .idea and node_modules folders
2. Restart IDE
3. run npm install

D) set the node_modules folder to NOT EXCLUDED

Option C works but as soon as I start the server again... code completion is gone -_-

Any idea what could be happening?

My guess there is something the IDE is changing when running the server and somehow it lost angular folders for code completion inside the node_modules folder.

IDE VERSION: INTELLIJ IDEA 2020.1

Comment: Please try the current IDE release: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. Do you have the same issue? Report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached using Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.